# Connecting Google Cloud SQL using Google Kubernetes: Insufficient Permission - GenerateEphemeralCert

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql, identity-management

I am trying to connect to MySQL CLoud SQL using GKE. I am using Spring Boot. But I cant establish the connection to the database.

I followed information from
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine

I've created the service account and service account name and bindings as given in the documentation. I even went ahead and gave a "Owner" IAM role for the service account, but the problem still persists. I'm pretty sure that the db credential secrets are correct, and can access the database in appengine and through db clients.

I get the following error:

```
{
  "code": 403,
  "details": [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
      "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
      "domain": "googleapis.com",
      "metadata": {
        "method": "google.cloud.sql.v1beta4.SqlConnectService.GenerateEphemeralCert",
        "service": "sqladmin.googleapis.com"
      }
    }
  ],
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Insufficient Permission",
      "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Full-stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get valid instance data within 45000 ms. Last refresh attempt failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: [my-gcloud-project:us-central1:my-gcloud-project-v1] Failed to create ephemeral certificate for the Cloud SQL instance.
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.Refresher.getConnectionInfo(Refresher.java:114) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.15.1.jar!/:1.15.1]
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.DefaultConnectionInfoCache.getConnectionInfo(DefaultConnectionInfoCache.java:92) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.15.1.jar!/:1.15.1]
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.DefaultConnectionInfoCache.createSslSocket(DefaultConnectionInfoCache.java:101) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.15.1.jar!/:1.15.1]
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.Connector.connect(Connector.java:113) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.15.1.jar!/:1.15.1]
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.InternalConnectorRegistry.connect(InternalConnectorRegistry.java:179) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.15.1.jar!/:1.15.1]
        at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:63) ~[mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8-1.15.1.jar!/:1.15.1]
        at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:45) ~[mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8-1.15.1.jar!/:1.15.1]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:62) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:935) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:805) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:438) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:189) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:48) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:?]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:75) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:?]
        at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:147) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:?]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:124) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.18.jar!/:2.7.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: [my-gcloud-project:us-central1:my-gcloud-project-v1] Failed to create ephemeral certificate for the Cloud SQL instance.
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:594) ~[guava-33.0.0-jre.jar!/:?]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:553) ~[guava-33.0.0-jre.jar!/:?]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:110) ~[guava-33.0.0-jre.jar!/:?]
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.Refresher.handleRefreshResult(Refresher.java:196) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.15.1.jar!/:1.15.1]
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.Refresher.lambda$startRefreshAttempt$1(Refresher.java:188) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.15.1.jar!/:1.15.1]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.CombinedFuture$AsyncCallableInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(CombinedFuture.java:165) ~[guava-33.0.0-jre.jar!/:?]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.CombinedFuture$AsyncCallableInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(CombinedFuture.java:153) ~[guava-33.0.0-jre.jar!/:?]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:76) ~[guava-33.0.0-jre.jar!/:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [my-gcloud-project:us-central1:my-gcloud-project-v1] Failed to create ephemeral certificate for the Cloud SQL instance.
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.DefaultConnectionInfoRepository.addExceptionContext(DefaultConnectionInfoRepository.java:408) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.15.1.jar!/:1.15.1]
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.DefaultConnectionInfoRepository.fetchEphemeralCertificate(DefaultConnectionInfoRepository.java:278) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.15.1.jar!/:1.15.1]
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.DefaultConnectionInfoRepository.lambda$getConnectionInfo$1(DefaultConnectionInfoRepository.java:112) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.15.1.jar!/:1.15.1]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.CombinedFuture$CallableInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(CombinedFuture.java:196) ~[guava-33.0.0-jre.jar!/:?]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:76) ~[guava-33.0.0-jre.jar!/:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
POST https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/my-gcloud-project/instances/my-gcloud-project-v1:generateEphemeralCert
{
  "code": 403,
  "details": [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
      "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
      "domain": "googleapis.com",
      "metadata": {
        "method": "google.cloud.sql.v1beta4.SqlConnectService.GenerateEphemeralCert",
        "service": "sqladmin.googleapis.com"
      }
    }
  ],
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Insufficient Permission",
      "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146) ~[google-api-client-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:118) ~[google-api-client-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:37) ~[google-api-client-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$3.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:466) ~[google-api-client-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1111) ~[google-http-client-1.43.3.jar!/:1.43.3]
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:552) ~[google-api-client-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:493) ~[google-api-client-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:603) ~[google-api-client-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.DefaultConnectionInfoRepository.fetchEphemeralCertificate(DefaultConnectionInfoRepository.java:276) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.15.1.jar!/:1.15.1]
        at com.google.cloud.sql.core.DefaultConnectionInfoRepository.lambda$getConnectionInfo$1(DefaultConnectionInfoRepository.java:112) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.15.1.jar!/:1.15.1]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.CombinedFuture$CallableInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(CombinedFuture.java:196) ~[guava-33.0.0-jre.jar!/:?]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:76) ~[guava-33.0.0-jre.jar!/:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
```

Deployment yaml file: (Edited - added the sql-cloud-proxy side-car pattern)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-gcloud-services
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-gcloud-services
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-gcloud-services
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: ksa-cloud-sql #my-gcloud-gke-service-account
      containers:
      - name: my-gcloud-services
        image: gcr.io/my-gcloud-project/my-gcloud-services:gke1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080  # Your application port
        env:
        - name: PORT
          value: "8080"
        - name: INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME
          value: my-gcloud-project:us-central1:my-gcloud-project-v1
        - name: DB_HOST
          value: "127.0.0.1"
        - name: DB_PORT
          value: "3306"
        - name: DB_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sql-credentials
              key: username
        - name: DB_PASS
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sql-credentials
              key: password
        - name: DB_NAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sql-credentials
              key: database
      - name: cloud-sql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy:2.8.0
        args:
          - "--structured-logs"
          - "--port=3306"
          - "my-gcloud-project:us-central1:my-gcloud-project-v1"
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
```

The application has data connection config in application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db?serverTimezone=UTC
    username: my-db-username
    password: my-db-password
```

Any pointers leading to a solution would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have a permission problem. Edit your question with the IAM Roles assigned to the principal (service account).

Comment: Do you mean setting "--auto-iam-authn" in args for cloud-sql-proxy. I had missed the cloud-sql-proxy while posting it here, I added it. When I create the cluster, if I assign a service account(appengine that works on appengine apps), then it's fine. But for the default compute engine service account it doesn't. I'd ideally want to create separate service account or at least use the default computer engine service account.

Comment: Adding the scope `--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` when building GKE clusters fixed the issue. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can double check is the host VM's access scope.
Steps:

- Stop the VM where you ran your program from.
- Check the access scope by clicking on edit button of this VM. Check the "allow full access to all Cloud APIs"

[image]

- Restart the VM and try to run the program again.

Eno also gave very good suggestions in GitHub. Copied it here (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy/issues/2104#issuecomment-1906512533) to share with those who are interested.

Comment: It didn't allow me to change any of the service account stuffs on the VM because it is assigned through GKE cluster. I attempted on a standalone VM, and it worked when I used a different service account (appengine related - the app was originally on appengine and it works there). However, when I point the default compute engine service account, it doesn't. The roles on both the service account are the same. The VM has full access to all CLoud APIs. It looks like an IAM/service-account) issue.

Comment: Adding the scope `--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` when building GKE clusters fixed the issue. Thank you.